# TCPDF Adding blur effect to shadow on Text

Tags: php, pdf, text, tcpdf, shadow

Hy
I'm working with TCPDF and I need to add some shadows to some text. This shadow should have a blur effect but I can't find any way to add it. This is my actual code

```
 $pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled' => true,
                            'depth_w' => $offsetX,
                            'depth_h' => $offsetY,
                            'color' => $color,
                            'opacity' => 1,
                            'blend_mode' => 'Normal'));
```

But there is no parameter for the blur effect, is there a way to add it or TCPDF simply dosn't provide a blur effect option?
thank's in advice

Comment: "Blur" and "Shadow" are no functions the PDF document model, so you have to write code to do it yourself. (Free thinking: use a gray duplicate of the original text and offset it a bit for a fake shadow. Perhaps you can add a lot of outlines around the text, starting with dark gray and making them lighter on each step.)

Comment: Thank's @Jongware I understand your point, but as there is a setTextShadow shouldn't be a setTextShadowBlur? otherwise how can TCPDF design the shadow?